# Changing default WIFI connection from repeater to router in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

I am using a repeater on my network. My system settings only shows one device name for a WIFI connection. It is defaulting my WIFI connection to the repeater instead of my router. `iwlist scan` shows both the repeater and router. How do I change my default connection to my router? Im guessing by MAC address somehow?

`nmcli device wifi list` returns-

[image]

My system is picking the weakest signal but the highest rate. I don't want that. My router is 10 feet away from my laptop.

Here is the short version of `iwlist`:

```
iwlist scan
wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 3C:37:86:12:A3:A8
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"trinity"

      Cell 03 - Address: C0:C5:22:4C:9E:D0
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"trinity"
```

It is MAC `C0:C5:22:4C:9E:D0` that I prefer to connect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would discourage tying your computer to only the router. The whole point of the router and repeater is to let the computer select the strongest signal to connect to.

However, to do what you wish, you'll need the SSID and BSSID of the router. Edit an existing wireless connection profile that already connects to the desired wireless network. The SSID will already be filled in. Now select the BSSID that matches your router, and you're done.

The BSSID can be found on the MAC address label on the router, or by using the `nmcli device wifi list` command, or by clicking on the down arrow in the BSSID field.

[image]

Another thing that can be done is to create two connection profiles, named, say, Trinity-Router and Trinity-Repeater, each hardwired to a different BSSID, and assign priorities. Use `nm-connection-editor`...

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you explain that the BSSID is the MAC address and how to find it:  `nmcli device wifi list` Thanks!

Comment: @chili555 Done. Thanks!

Comment: @chili555 Thanks, I updated my question

Comment: @heynnema I appreciate your answer but my computer is picking the weakest signal.

Comment: @stumblebee So my answer provides the answer that you need, correct? Just set the proper BSSID. BTW, you typed the `nmcli device wifi list` incorrectly, so it didn't show the BSSIDs.

Comment: @stumblebee Please see the update in my answer.

Comment: @heynnema `nmcli device wifi list` provides the same result as `nmcli dev wifi list` `sudo iwlist scan` provided the MAC addresses. When I put the MAC address in the BSSID field, it did switch connections, I did not know BSSD was also the MAC address. Thank you for your answer and being patient with my mis-understanding.